# Use a dynamic logName in an Apache Camel route

Tags: logging, apache-camel, log4j

I'm using Camel and Log4J and within my routes I'm using log messages like this

```
<log message="This is a test" loggingLevel="TRACE" logName="com.acme.logfile1"/>
```

My goal is, depending on certain criteria, to log messages to different loggers that I have defined in my log4j.properties.

If I hard code in different logNames, my messages go to the appropriate files

`<log message="This is a test" loggingLevel="TRACE" logName="com.acme.logfile1"/>` goes to logfile 1

`<log message="This is a test" loggingLevel="TRACE" logName="com.acme.logfile2"/>` goes to logfile 2

I'd like to use a header value called "logfile" to determine which logfile to write to and have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
<log message="This is a test for com.acme.${in.headers.logfile}" loggingLevel="TRACE" logName="com.acme.${in.headers.logfile}"/>
```

I know that my header is set correctly as if I do this I see the appropriate value in my logfile1 (assuming ${in.headers.logfile} = foobar)

```
<log message="This is a test for com.acme.${in.headers.logfile}" loggingLevel="TRACE" logName="com.acme.logfile1"/>
```

I see "This is a test for com.acme.foobar" in my logfile1

So - is there a way to dynamically direct logs to different loggers in my routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my Processor, I am using for dynamic logger. Feel free to use it. This processoor uses [Expression](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Expression.html) to convert Simple language to String and [CamelLogger](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/util/CamelLogger.html) to log message. Suffix of logName is determined by `logger` header;

```
public class CustomLogger implements Processor {
    private static final String LOGGER_PREFIX = "com.acme";

    final String simple;
    final LoggingLevel level;

    public CustomLogger(String simple, LoggingLevel level) {
        this.simple = simple;
        this.level = level;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Expression expression = exchange.getContext().resolveLanguage("simple").createExpression(simple);
        new CamelLogger(
                String.format("%s.%s", LOGGER_PREFIX, exchange.getIn().getHeader("logger", "default")),
                level
        ).log(expression.evaluate(exchange, String.class));
    }
}
```

Usage

```
from("direct:someRoute")
    .process(new CustomLogger("This should go to ${in.headers.logger} logger", LoggingLevel.INFO))
    .to("log:done");
```

Answer (score 1):

No not using the `<log>` in the Camel route. That is static. You can use a `<bean>` or `<processor>` and in the Java code you, you can write some Java code that logs dynamically.